How do I get the accesstoken for my active user from azure so I can connect to my db?
In an Azure hosted Blazor .NET 8.0 web app, I have a service I have created for accessing my azure hosted SQL Server DB.
Its declared in my Program.cs like this:
builder.Services.AddScoped<DataAccessService>();

The constructor for my service looks like this:
        public DataAccessService(ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition, IConfiguration configuration, AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider)
    {
        _config = configuration;
        _tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
        _authenticationStateProvider = authenticationStateProvider;
    }

Note that I'm injecting tokenAcquisition and AuthenticationStateProvider.
In a method in the service I have the following code:
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        SqlDataReader dr = null!;   
        
        var authState = _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync().Result;

        var acc = authState.User;

        var accessToken = _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes: new[] { "https://database.windows.net/.default" }, user: acc).Result; 

        con.AccessToken = accessToken;

The GetAuthenticationStateAsync call uses .Result at the moment, I will sort that out once I get everything else working...
When I get to the GetAccessTokenForUserAsync I get the following errors:

Inner Exception 1:
MicrosoftIdentityWebChallengeUserException: IDW10502: An MsalUiRequiredException was thrown due to a challenge for the user. See https://aka.ms/ms-id-web/ca_incremental-consent.
Inner Exception 2:
MsalUiRequiredException: No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call.

My user has already been authenticated by this point (you can't actually get to this bit of code without being an authenticated user). Why am I getting these errors and how do I avoid them so I can get the token?
